# Can you use PHP Session on a file called by another domain?

Tags: php, session, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have a php file on `external-site.com` like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['something'] == true) {
//do something
}
?>
```

This PHP file I include on a different website `example.com` like this:

```
<script src="http://external-site.com/session.js.php"></script>
```

When the visitor visits `example.com` he is redirected to `external-site.com`. Here I have this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = true;
?>
```

And then the visitor is immediately redirected back to `example.com`.

Does this work? Because I am not violating the Same Origin Policy, right? I do **not** want to use the session on `example.com` itself. I only need it for `external-site.com`. So I do **not** want to transfer the session to another domain or anything like that.

If so, in which browser does it work and in which browser it does not?

Comment: session will only be visible for your site only

Comment: This answer does not help. Which "your site" do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Session are only available on the site which host the session calls.if you have two sites, they can't share natively session.

Edit : so if your session is opened on external -ite.com, you can't use it on example.com. in your case you need to use a SSO service.